# Erro com OG:TAGS do facebook

Tags: facebook, html-meta-tag, opencart

Estou com um problema com `og:tag` do facebook ,tenho um [e-commerce](http://oticasreiban.com.br/) feito com opencart, para poder compartilhar links no facebook tive que usar essas `tags` porém estou com o seguinte problema, adicionei essas `tags` para poder aparecer um icone da loja quando compartilhar no facebook apra debugar estou usando essa [ferramenta](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Foticasreiban.com.br%2Faliancas) quando debugo a `home` e a sessão de relógios funciona normalmente como mostra a imagem abaixo:

HOME:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

RELÓGIOS:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

até aqui tudo está funcionando como esperado porem vejam o que acontece quando debugo a sessão óculos e alianças:

OCULOS:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

ALIANÇA:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

percebam que no preview mostra a foto de um relógio quando na verdade teria que aparecer somente o logo como nas duas primeiras imagens não sei porque funciona em algumas sessões e outras não, segue minhas `meta tags` para análise:

de inicio tentei deixar assim e funcionou porem acontece esse problema acima somente pega a sessão relógios e a sessão `home` o restante não adiciona a imagem correta.

```
    <meta property="og:title" content="Óticas Reiban" />
    <meta property="og:locale" content="pt_BR" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://oticasreiban.com.br" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="A Reiban é uma empresa de e-commerce, especializada no varejo on-line. Com a grande aposta na internet como um meio fácil, eficiente e seguro para se comprar, surgiu a ideia e necessidade" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://oticasreiban.com.br/image/catalog/logo-reiban-facebbok.jpg" />
```

e mesmo tentando colocar todas as `urls` das sessões nas metas não funciona continua dando o mesmo problema somente funcionando corretamente nas duas primeiras sessões listadas:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Óticas Reiban" />
<meta property="og:locale" content="pt_BR" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://oticasreiban.com.br" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://oticasreiban.com.br/aliancas" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://oticasreiban.com.br/relogios" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://oticasreiban.com.br/oculos-de-sol" />
<meta property="og:description" content="A Reiban é uma empresa de e-commerce, especializada no varejo on-line. Com a grande aposta na internet como um meio fácil, eficiente e seguro para se comprar, surgiu a ideia e necessidade" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://oticasreiban.com.br/image/catalog/logo-reiban-facebbok.jpg" />
```

OBS: qualquer um desses dois modelos que usei funciona certo somente na sessão home e relógios e dando erro nos óculos e nas alianças.

Answer (score 0):

Tente colocar uma og:url para sua respectiva página.

Exemplo:

Na página http://oticasreiban.com.br/relogios

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://oticasreiban.com.br/relogios" />
```

E assim por diante.